# unityってオフラインで使えますか？

Tags: unity3d

タイトルの通りです。
unityのインストールはすんでいて、今すぐにでも使える状態です。

Answer (score 2):

はい。
今すぐにでもオフラインでお使いいただけます。

ただしライセンスの[アクティベーション](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2020.1/Manual/OnlineActivationGuide.html)が済んでいるならば。
オフラインで[マニュアルアクティベーション](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2020.1/Manual/ManualActivationGuide.html)することも可能ですが、若干面倒な手続きを踏むことになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　参考になりました。